# SSIS Package works in IDE but does not after deployment

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ssis

So I have this SSIS package that works flawlessly when I start it within Visual Studio Integration 2012. However when I deploy this package via the SQL Catalog it neither works or breaks. It just runs with no output.

I have no idea why this is. My package is simple.

1. Query a DB table
2. Place data into a `Recordset Destination` using a local variable
3. Pass the local variable along with some project parameters into a script that is embedded into a sequence > foreach container. The script then updates the same db table with a new value based on the logic within the script and it also sends out an email using the data pulled from the query.

I know that my query in #1 is working. I can see it through my job execution reports... it writes in all rows from the DB table. Then it just sits in my script doing God knows what... So I am guessing since it is not my query it must be one of the project params/connections (that I set using an environment). Here is my syntax for these. Do you see anything wrong with them? Please ignore the code I left out as I am sure it is not breaking there. Also I am 100% positive I am setting the values correctly in my environment and that they are properly assigned in the package.

Here is my relevant code snippets (do not mind order):

```
        Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter
        oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables("User::CustomerRows").Value)
        ScriptMain.Wrapper = New ET_AutoRenewal.WrapperClass(Dts.Variables("$Project::etUserName").Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables("$Project::etPassword").Value.ToString())

        Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("test")

        Dim sqlConn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim sqlCmdText As String
        sqlConn = DirectCast(Dts.Connections("test").AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction), SqlClient.SqlConnection)
        sqlCmdText = "UPDATE [" + Dts.Variables("$Project::sDatabaseName").Value.ToString() + "].[dbo].[temp_AutoRenewal_listpull] SET [process_flag] = 1 WHERE [confirmation_num] = '" + xmlDict.Item("confirmation_num") + "'"
```

So if that all looks good, which to me it does. How could this happen, it works fine in VS but not when deployed. What is more frustrating is nothing fails, it simply runs and there is no output (ie no table updates or emails sent out).

Are there any techniques to debug a deployed package?

Comment: Is the deployed package configured to run under an account that has rights to access the database?

Comment: Can you turn on verbose logging?

Comment: Is $Project::etPassword marked as sensitive? I assume *not*, as I think accessing as it does raises an exception but I'm too lazy to go find an example. Have you thought about putting in calls to `Dts.Events.FireInformation`? That would allow you to better trace what values your script is acting upon. Also, as DaveE mentioned, turn on verbose logging for maximum information but you ought to be able to see start and stop times for the tasks in the control flow with the default logging level. Check the log, perhaps the Script task never fires. `SELECT * FROM catalog.operational_messages`

Comment: @DeanOC checked the service accounts as well. All good.

Comment: @billinkc you're assumption is right, they are not sensitive. I have done `FireInformation` but only in the exception handling, which is never called due to the fact that there are no thrown exceptions, so I will add that. As for verbose logging, I'll need to look into that as well, thank you. If I can figure it out due to those suggestions I will post the answer if not I will come back with an update.

Comment: You could use profiler to see if the SQL commands in your script task are being executed on the SQL server.   Since you're doing updates, I'm thinking maybe a deadlock/blocking is occurring.

Comment: @billinkc your debugging technique with `Dts.Events.FireInformation` and `SELECT * FROM catalog.operational_messages` lead me to discover my problem, which was: trying to reference an assembly within my script that was not in the `GAC` after deploying the package to the catalog. If you'd like to put your comment into an answer I will accept it. Thanks again.